# My product can not show image

Tags: product

What is that problem?
src="http://magento.demo2.com/media/catalog/product%5Ccache%5Ca3a5fab46ded5c197ff7844fd9e08957%5C//u/r/urn_aaid_sc_us_a1b326b9-062f-484a-b97d-39dbdbe93333_1_3_1_1.png"
[image]

Comment: run command after check. -> php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile 
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
bin/magento cache:clean 
run this commands
```

Comment: It's worked, thank for your help